# Drools Condition matching failing

Tags: drools

I am using Drools 4 and when I am comparing two hashmap values with == it is not working. All other operators like >=,<=,<,>,!= are working fine.  I am comparing as below.  I am using map as .  Is there any thing wrong with the statement.  The map values will be updated in actions of the rules. I am able to see the updated values in map but comparison of the values is failing. I am using update(abc) to update the values.

eval((abc.getValue("123")).intValue() == (abc.getValue("456")).intValue())

**Rule:**

```
rule "008"
salience -18
agenda-group  "CAP"
auto-focus true
when 
  testObj: TestObj(eval(fireNextPriority==true), categoryCount==18,
       eval(!firedRules.contains(Integer.valueOf(23449))) 
 && (date >= 1263925800000)
 && (date <= 4102338600000) && (date >= 1263925800000) && (date <= 4102338600000)
 && eval(1 == 1)  
 && eval(testObj.getVariableValue("C1TC") == testObj.getVariableValue("Y1TC")))

then
  System.out.println("Firing rule: CAP - 008");
  testObj.setStatus(true);
  testObj.setPriority(1);
  testObj.addToFiredRules(23449);
  update(testObj);      
  testObj.addVariableValue("C1PC", testObj.getVariableValue("C1PC")-
  testObj.getVariableValue("C1OF"));
 end
```

***Object which we are using:***

```
public class TestObj{
   Long date;
   Integer categoryCount;
   boolean status = false;
   boolean executeFinalRule = false;
   boolean executeFinalRuleForCatg = true;
   boolean fireNextPriority = true;
   Set<Integer> firedRules = new HashSet<Integer>();
   private int priority;
   Map<String, Integer> variableValues = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
   public Integer getCategoryCount() {
     return categoryCount;
   }
   public void setCategoryCount(Integer categoryCount) {
     this.categoryCount = categoryCount;
   }
   public void increaseCategoryCount(){
     this.categoryCount++;
   }
   public void addVariableValue(String variableCode, Integer count){
     if (count < 0) count = 0;
     this.variableValues.put(variableCode, count);
   }
   public Integer getVariableValue(String variableCode){
     Integer value = this.variableValues.get(variableCode);
     return value == null? 0 : value;
   }
   public boolean isStatus() {
     return status;
   }
   public Set<Integer> getFiredRules() {
    return firedRules;
   }
   public void setFiredRules(Set<Integer> firedRules) {
     this.firedRules = firedRules;
   }
   public void addToFiredRules(int l){
    this.firedRules.add(l);
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that Drools 4 is extremely outdated, and not much supported. - There's a lot of possible reasons why you don't obtain the expected result, but it's impossible to say more without a complete rule. How is abc declared? Where is the maps you've mentioned? Also, show the rule where the update is being made!

Comment: Hi Laune thanks for quick response.  I updated the my question with the details. The rule will update map values in object and which are the input for the next rules.  == is failing in condition

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Drools 4.x, so these are observations based of my (old) knowledge of 5.1.1 - they may not be accurate in your case.

```
 eval(fireNextPriority==true)
```

It's remarkable that this works. `eval` does not maintain the context of the enclosing pattern (fact), so normally you'd have to write

```
 eval(!firedRules.contains(Integer.valueOf(23449))
```

Same thing.

```
 eval(testObj.getVariableValue("C1TC") == testObj.getVariableValue("Y1TC"))
```

This is as I'd write it from 5.1 onwards.

The strange thing is

```
testObj.addVariableValue("C1PC", testObj.getVariableValue("C1PC")
testObj.getVariableValue("C1OF"));
```

(DID I MESS THIS UP WHILE EDITING?) These changes are *after* the `update` call, which means that they won't be seen by the engine. Has the update of map entries "C1TC" and/or "Y1TC" been done likewise in another rule? Then they won't be equal to Drools, even if they are to Java...

Comment: Thanks Laune.  even I tried the update as last statement but updated values is not available for the next rule condition.  In my case modified value should be available for the next rule condition.  equals is failing because the updated values is not updated in drools and is available for java.